# Resistor becoming parallel when short circuited Thevenin's

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

Why does resistor R1 suddenly become parallel to R2 once the supply is shorted (to calculate Thevenin's resistance)?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Parallel is in regard to potential, Let's call point $A$ the point between the resistors, and $B$ the point on top of $R_1$, and $C$ below $R_2$. Once the source is shorted, you can clearly see that the potential $V_{AB}$(Between $A$ and $B$) is equal to $V_{AC}$ as $V_{BC}=0$ ( No elements in between ), thus the two resistors are indeed in parallel by definition.

Comment: Obviously they'll all have zero potential because there is no EMF in the first place.

Comment: Thevenin doesn't work that way, you calculate  the equivalent source ($e_{Th}$ ) by cutting off the charge and calculating the potential at it's points ( the potential at $R_2$ in this case ) and the equivalent resistor by shorting the free sources and  putting a source $e_{Th}$ at the charge and calculating the fraction $V_{exit}/I_{exit}$. and you get $R_2$.

Comment: So I have to imagine that current is flowing from B?

Comment: Exactly. Check Wikipedia's page on it.

Comment: *"and the equivalent resistor by shorting the free sources"* - this is misleading at best.  One doesn't 'short' the sources, one *zeros* the sources , i.e, replace each voltage source with a '0 V source' (a wire) and each current source with a '0 A source' (an open).

Answer (score 0):

With the voltage source *zeroed* (replace the voltage source with a wire), the 'top' lead of $R_1$ is connected to the same node, node B, as the 'bottom' lead of $R_2$.

Thus, one lead of each resistor is connected to node A while the other lead of each resistor is connected to node B.

In other words, with the voltage source zeroed, both resistors are connected between nodes A and B and so the resistors are parallel connected.

As a sanity check, imagine connecting a *test voltage source* between nodes A and B and see, by inspection, that both resistors have *identical* voltage across which defines parallel connected components.